# SwiftUI Glitches in FormView

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-form

I am facing some weird glitches in my `Form` implementation. I am not sure whether this is some implementation error or a bug in SwiftUI itself.

So basically what I want to do is the typical "ToDo/TimeTracking" app. I want to create a new task entity referenced to a project entity. Therefore I created a `Form` where I can select a project, set the title and notes of the task as well as the start and end date.

But now I am experiencing some visual glitches.

1. When I select a project with the `Picker` I am getting navigated to a separate view (as expected) but the list from which I can select the the project is moving a little bit upwards after the page transition animation as finished.
2. When selecting "Already finished" and then selecting a date from the `DatePicker` and closing the picker, the picker glitches around inside the view before it gets hidden.

A minimal viable example can be achieved with the following code snippet:

```
mport SwiftUI

struct Project {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
}

let projects = [Project(id: 0, title: "Hello"),Project(id: 1, title: "World")]

struct ContentView: View {

     @State private var showingCreateTask = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
             Text("Hello, World!")
            .navigationBarTitle("Test")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { self.showingCreateTask.toggle() }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus").imageScale(.large)
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingCreateTask) {
                    CreateTaskView(projects: projects)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CreateTaskView: View {

    let projects: [Project]

    @State private var selectedProject = 0
    @State private var taskTitle: String = ""
    @State private var taskNotes: String = ""
    @State private var alreadyFinished = false

    @State private var startDate = Date()
    @State private var endDate = Date()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedProject, label: Text("Project")) {
                        ForEach(0..<self.projects.count) { index in
                            Text(self.projects[index].title)
                        }
                    }
                }

                Section {
                    TextField("Title", text: $taskTitle)
                    TextField("Notes", text: $taskNotes)
                    Toggle(isOn: $alreadyFinished) {
                        Text("Already finished ?")
                    }
                }

                if alreadyFinished {
                    Section {
                        DatePicker(selection: $startDate, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]) {
                            Text("Start Date")
                        }
                        DatePicker(selection: $endDate, in: startDate..., displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]) {
                            Text("End Date")
                        }
                    }
                }

                Button(action: {
                }) {
                    Text("Save changes")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Create a new task")
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe someone has experienced something similar and knows whether this is an SwiftUI Bug or some error in my code. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Video of Bug]

Comment: When I select a project with the Picker I am getting navigated to a separate view (as expected) but the list from which I can select the the project is moving a little bit upwards after the page transition animation as finished.    Do you see it in simulator or also on device ? Looks like some layout is done after loading and then the 2 fields move up. But should not be noticeable on a device.

Comment: Unfortunately the same glitch as in the simulator happens on a device as well.

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58982296/12202752 Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may improve it like this:

```
                       NavigationView {
                    Form {
                        Section {
                            Picker(selection: $selectedProject, label: Text("Project")) {
                                ForEach(0..<self.projects.count) { index in
                                    Text(self.projects[index].title).tag(index)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                                       Section {
                                                          TextField("Title", text: $taskTitle)
                                                          TextField("Notes", text: $taskNotes)
                                                          Toggle(isOn: $alreadyFinished) {
                                                              Text("Already finished ?")
                                                          }
                                                      }

                                       Button(action: {
                                       }) {
                                           Text("Save changes")
                                       }

                        if alreadyFinished {
                            Section {

                                DatePicker(selection: $startDate,in: startDate..., displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]) {
                                    Text("Start Date")
                                }}
                             Section {
                                DatePicker(selection: $endDate, in: startDate..., displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]) {
                                    Text("End Date")
                                    }
                            }.transition(AnyTransition.identity.animation(nil))
                        }


                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Create a new task", displayMode: .inline)
                }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your improvements. Indeed it improves the visual glitches but still they are not gone completely. The selection list still moves on the first appearance - now the cell items are moving a little bit to the left on appear. So but I assume that those glitches are SwiftUI related and a code problem per se?

Comment: You should file a bug I fear.